# Compare Optional Bool variable doesn't work

Tags: arrays, swift, boolean, option-type

I have to create a 2D `Array` of Optional `Bool` type and compare the value inside it but I can't. 
The first time I try to declare in this way:

```
var Answ = [[Bool?]] ()
var Page = 0 

for i in 0...4
{
    if Answ[Page][i] ==  true
    {...}

    else if Answ[Page][I] == false
    {...}

    else
    {...}

}
...
```

but when I launch the program, it says:

> index out of range

when Xcode compares the `Answ[Page][i]` with the value `true`.

So, I try to modify the code and declare the array in this way:

```
var Answ = Array (repeating: Array (repeating: Bool?.self , count: 5), count: 40)
var Page = 0 

for i in 0...4
{
    if Answ[Page][i] ==  true
    {...}

    else if Answ[Page][I] == false
    {...}

    else
    {...}

}
...
```

but at the same point, `(if Answ[Page][i] ==  true)` throws this error:

> Binary operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'Bool?.Type' (aka 'optional.Type') and 'Bool'"

Moreover, in other points of the code where I try to set a value of the array as true/false (`Answ[Page][2] = true`), Xcode says this:

> cannot assign value of type 'Bool' to type 'Bool?.Type' (Aka'Optional.Type')

Can someone help me, please? Thank you in advance.

I found this topic:

[Checking the value of an Optional Bool](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25523305/checking-the-value-of-an-optional-bool)

but it didn't help me much.

Comment: variable names should be lower camelcase to prevent confusion with types

Comment: Following the Apple doc, you should compare two booleans with `==` https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/bool/2430796. Maybe, the value you're getting with `[Page][2]` is not a bool

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You *can* compare optional bools as in the Q&A that you linked to. The problem is that

```
var Answ = Array (repeating: Array (repeating: Bool?.self , count: 5), count: 40)
```

creates a (nested) array of `Bool?.self`, which is the *type* of an optional bool, not a *value* of that type.

What you want is a (nested) array of `Bool?` *values,* initialized to `nil`:

```
var answers: [[Bool?]] = Array(repeating: Array(repeating: nil , count: 5), count: 40)
```

or alternatively:

```
var answers = Array(repeating: Array(repeating: Bool?.none , count: 5), count: 40)
```

Comment: Thank you, now the code is working. If I can return the favor say me ;)

Answer (score 0):

You should provide a **fallback value** with `??`.

By the way, you don't need to write `== false` or `== true`, it's redundant.

```
if Answ[Page][i] ?? false {
    [...]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several issues with your code. First of all, don't use manual indexing in a for loop, rather use `for ... in` to have the indexes automatically handled for you. Secondly, a better solution for handling optional booleans is to safely unwrap the value using optional binding and then check the non-optional value. You also don't need to write `if bool == true`, `if bool` has the same meaning.

Also please make sure you conform to the Swift naming convention, which is lower-camelCase for variable names.

```
var answ = [[Bool?]] ()
var page = 0

for ans in answ[page]{
    if let unwrappedAns = ans {
        if unwrappedAns {
            // answ[page][i] = true
        } else {

        }
    } else {
        //answ[page][i] = ans is nil
    }
}
```

If you actually want to iterate through the whole array of arrays, this is one safe way for doing so:

```
for page in answ {
    for ans in page {
        //here ans = Answ[Page][i] when compared to the code in your question
        if let unwrappedAns = ans {
            if unwrappedAns {

            } else {

            }
        } else {
            //ans is nil
        }
    }
}
```